# IF I can protect wwwroot folder or my project folder with a password, will IIS be able to read the folder?

Tags: directory, passwords, iis-8, password-protection, password-encryption

I want to protect my wwwroot folder or my project folder (which serves the code for my web application) with a password.
How can I do that?
If I do that will IIS be able to read the contents of the password protected folder?

I have 2 admins for one windows server but I want only one admin to be able to access a password protected folder, and the password protected folder should be accessible to IIS

Comment: "protect my wwwroot folder or my project folder (which serves the code for my web application) with a password". Ask yourself why you wanted to share code via a web server. Besides, do you want to encrypt the file system or you want to configure IIS authentication/authorization? Those two are different concepts.

Comment: You can share your folders as network share folder, if you are using asp.net core, you can check [this blog](https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/05/17/network-path-for-static-files-in-asp-net-core-web-applications/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable non-anonymous authentication in IIS, authentication is done by getting a valid username and password on the internet or intranet system. After a user is authenticated, the system authorizes the user to access the application.

Windows Authentication is preferred if you are creating a web application for a limited number of users who already belong to a network domain.

Please open IIS, select the website or application that corresponds to your project folder. In the Features view, double-click the Authentication icon. Make sure "Windows Authentication" is enabled and all other authentication methods are disabled. You can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/) about Windows Authentication.

You also need to set specific permissions for the desired admin user, navigate to your project folder (eg wwwroot) >> right click on the folder and select "Properties" >> click the "Security" tab >> click " Edit button to modify permissions >> Click Add button to add the desired admin user >> Enter the name of the admin user and click Check Names to verify >> Click OK to add the user >> Grant Permissions required for the admin user.

The IIS_IUSRS group needs to have "read" permissions because this group represents the IIS worker process.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, here, changing the folder permission can be done by other admin as well, so if I assign the folder permissions to myself and not the other 2nd admin, the 2nd admin will be able to change the permissions of the folder and can make it available to themself.
Could you please help me if there is a way to protect it with password and allow IIS to use that folder?

Comment: Perhaps you could consider using an additional layer of security by implementing basic authentication at the application level in your web application. This way password protection can be enforced in the application's code independent of folder permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am more concerned with IIS being able to read the contents of the password protected code/folder. How can IIS read the contents of the folder in such case?